# CSS Padding param is not loading

Tags: html, css, padding, css-tables

[image]

This is a table (tag)
Where first column holds username
second column holds content for this particular topic

I've made a css for the table and definition within should set the padding to 0.
However, I noticed `padding: 0px 0px;` has no effect

Browser: Chrome

CSS for the topic

```
.TOPIC_STYLE {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border:0px solid black;
    padding:0px 0px;

    font-family: '华康少女文字 - Kelvin';
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #819FF7;
}
```

Here is the code for table: `<table class=TOPIC_STYLE align=left>`

2016-08-13 - Complete set of code is lost along with my old laptop.

Goal: Eliminate the white space in the red circle.

Other CSS I have for table:

```
                        .TOP_LEFT {
                                background-image: url(top_Left.png);
                                background-repeat: no-repeat;
                        }
                        .TOP_RIGHT {
                                background-image: url(top_Right.png);
                                background-repeat: no-repeat;
                        }
                        .VERTICAL_LEFT {
                                width:  150px;
                                height: 30px;

                                text-align: center;

                                background-image: url(vertical_Left.png);
                                background-repeat: repeat-y;
                        }
                        .VERTICAL_RIGHT {
                                width:  700px;
                                height: 30px;

                                background-image: url(vertical_Right.png);
                                background-repeat: repeat-y;
                        }
                        .BOTTOM_LEFT {
                                width:  150px;
                                height: 40px;

                                background-image: url(bottom_Left.png);
                                background-repeat: no-repeat;
                        }
                        .BOTTOM_RIGHT {
                                width:  700px;
                                height: 40px;

                                text-align: center;

                                background-image: url(bottom_Right.png);
                                background-repeat: no-repeat;
                        }
```

Solution:

Pictures was indeed used to create the border, which was unnecessary since CSS already provided border property for that purpose.
Therefore all related pictures can be shelved and use border property instead.
Similarly, border-left, right, top, bottom can also be used.

```
table {
    border: 2px solid red;
}
```

Comment: shouldn't it be `class="TOPIC_STYLE"`?

Comment: sorry.. I have another php variable named $TOPIC_STYLE holding the style name.. but it works fine except for padding.. I should change that for less confusion..

Comment: you'd still need quotes around the classname to make it valid html, in any case.

Comment: works fine for other style i created..

Comment: "works fine" and "correct" are two different things.

Comment: Can you provide a functional HTML and CSS example for us to look at?  You can either hot-link the images, or Base 64 encode them (http://www.base64-image.de/step-1.php).

Comment: @MarcB ok>_< so.. it is i did not give expected result.. which is incorrect (learned).

Comment: @Katiek I have link to my website.. It is working with no error except this one and I have just refreshed it and checked.. Not sure if you need php.. but i'll put it in a php.txt file.. (You can see dir in my server since i'm still noob in server hosting =\ ) * php.txt added..

Comment: FYI - You'll get better help if your questions contain a good example - see http://sscce.org/. The best questions are free of errors / typos (try a code validator like http://validator.w3.org/) and contains just enough code to demonstrate the problem, without anything extra. Doing this can be a lot of work, but it's a critical part of troubleshooting your problem.

Comment: @KatieK thanks for the good site but i'm running out of time =\ I have another 20 hours and 32 minutes to get everything done.. i'll live the error for now.. thanks.. i will come back later..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your background image isn't wide enough to cover all the space without repeating.  For `.TOP_LEFT`, change `background-repeat:` to `repeat-x;` and edit a new image to be much taller and wider.

But if I were in your shoes, I'd just handle that effect as a border.  Take off all of the background images and add these rules:

```
table { border: 2px solid blue; border-collapse: collapse; }
tr { border: 2px solid blue; }
```

Comment: New answer based on new example. :)

Comment: it works.. however it did not solve the padding problem.. Even i give `padding: 10px 10px;` it is not giving correct result also.. But i'll use this as alernative solution although kinda weird, tks..

Comment: Yeah, `border-collapse: collapse;` negates padding on a table element. If you really need spacing around the table, try a margin instead. Or perhaps what you're looking for is padding on the `td`s, not the table.

Comment: Yes, it is on tds.. columns.. I'll try that later on.. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why your class name has a dollar sign in front of it. Try this:

```
<table class="TOPIC_STYLE">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<table class="TOPIC_STYLE" align="left">
```

They should be look like this..Are you getting the same problem still ??

Comment: yes.. >_< I tried single quote now.. double quotation just tried.. did not correct it also..